# Can't remove mysql-server from Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get, mysql-5.7

I've gotten into a bad state with MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04, so I attempted to remove it. I thought I successfully removed it with `apt-get remove`, but now whenever I do an `apt-get` or something I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This seems to happen for any package I try to remove / install / etc. What's the best way to remove this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql